# Detect undo vs clear a range of multiple cells?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Inside of `onEdit()` function is there a way detect if user cleared a range or hit undo button?

For a single cell I'm successfully use:

```
function onEdit(e)
{
  const range = e.range;
  if (e.value === undefined && e.oldValue === undefined)
  {
    /* undo */
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("undo");
  }
  else if (range.isBlank())
  {
    /* cleared */
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("cleared");
  }
  else
  {
    /* modified */
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("modified");
  }
}
```

Unfortunately when clearing multiple cells it thinks it's undo.

Comment: Does swapping the order of `undo` and `cleared` statements work on your case? see answer below for demo.

Answer (score 1):

You can try switching your conditions:

#### Modification:

```
function onEdit(e)
{
  const range = e.range;
  if (range.isBlank())
  {
    /* cleared */
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("cleared");
  }
  else if (e.value === undefined && e.oldValue === undefined)
  {
    /* undo */
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("undo");
  }
  else
  {
    /* modified */
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("modified");
  }
}
```

So when the range is blank, it is always going straight for cleared.

#### Clear:

[image: clear]

#### Issue:

- When you undo and the resulting range is blank, it will say cleared, but I guess that would be tolerable.

#### Undo issue:

[image: issue]

#### Note:

- When you copy and paste, event values will be undefined so it will show undo. I'm not sure what you can do to catch this.

Comment: Thank you. It's a decent work around, unfortunately I'm changing border color on cells (and the way it currently works you can't change 4 sides with different styles of the border in one step), which means when it clears, it adds 3 items into undo history, so when you undo, and script acts like its "clear" it adds back 3 more items, rendering undo unusable.

Comment: Yea, it's hard to do when apps script cant detect which specific triggers triggered the function. We can only depend on the values and it seems very impossible to do these kinds of things seamlessly when a lot of triggers output the same undefined values  (undo, redo, clear, etc.)